# Laravel Eloquent subquery and count subquery results

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Let's say there's a `Post` model. It has a `hasMany` relationship called `comments()` defined in its model.

I'm trying to:

- Get the count of comments
- That belongs to a specific set of Posts, defined by an array of ids
- Where the comments are posted in a certain date range

I thought the following would work:

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$results = Post::whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->with(['comments'])
    ->whereHas('comments', function($q) {
       $q->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month);
    })
    ->withCount('comments')
    ->get();
```

And then do

```
$count = array_sum($results->pluck('comments_count')->toArray());
```

The result of the query does include `comments_count` so that's working, and `$count` works as well.

But the date range in the subquery is not applied, it counts *all* comments. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to pass the same condition/subquery to the `withCount` method:

```
->withCount(['comments' => function($q) {
       $q->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month);
    }])
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_withCount